# Case management in git branch

Tags: git

I do not understand what happens when I

```
git checkout <branch_with_missed_upper_to_lower_case>
git checkout <branch_with_proper_case>
git branch -d <branch_with_missed_upper_to_lower_case>
```

Then I am in said "initial commit", can only `git checkout -f <elsewhere>` to leave the trap. All following commands fail aborting with uncommited changes or first commit not done (HEAD not set):

```
git stash
git stash -q
git checkout .
git checkout <elsewhere>
git clean -xfd
git reflog
```

I even had at some point

```
Rename from 'C:/wordirGit/ps-fw-fps/.git/HEAD.lock' to 'C:/wordirGit/ps-fw-fps/.git/HEAD' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

unable to `y`, when `git checkout -f <elsewhere>`.

Who could explain what happens after deleting  ?

- edit, I am using GitBash on Windows

Comment: Are you using Windows or MacOS, or some other system in which the files named `readme.md` and `README.md` are the same file?

Comment: good point : I am using gitbash on Windows. It does has it side effects indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the question here is not whether you can have branches whose name differs only in case, such as `branch` vs `BRANCH`.  (The answer to that is both yes and no: sometimes you can, and sometimes you can't.)  It is instead why, having created a branch named `BRANCH`, then created another branch named `branch`, having the branch named `branch` checked out, and deleting the branch named `BRANCH`, Git itself gets confused and is now in a bad state.

The answer in this case is "because of Windows", although it's more precisely because of the *file system* you are using on Windows.  MacOS has file systems that behave this way as well by default.

The short version is that you're running into Git's own internal confusing as to whether case is significant in branch names.

#### Long

Before we start, you need to know that the special file `.git/HEAD` contains the *name of the current branch*.  It is a plain-text file and consists of a single line, of the form `ref: refs/heads/name`.  The *`name`* part contains the current branch name.  (There is one other option: the file can exist and contain a raw hash ID instead.  This indicates that your repository is in detached HEAD mode.  The `HEAD` file *must* exist, though, otherwise this `.git` directory is not considered a repository at all.)

You also need to know that in Git, each *branch name* simply stores the hash ID of some existing commit.  It is not valid to *have* a branch name unless the stored hash ID is that of some existing commit.

#### Branch names in various files

Git believes, pretty strongly, that *branch* names `xyz` and `XYZ` are entirely different.  Microsoft and Apple tend to disagree: *files* named `xyz` and `XYZ` represent the *same* file.

Git was initially written on Linux, and Linux file systems tend to agree with Git: a file named `xyz` is completely separate from some other file named `XYZ`, so you can have both at the same time.  Git took advantage of this property.

Now, Git doesn't store all branch names as file names.  In fact, branch names *aren't* file names in many cases.  For instance, when you first clone a repository, your Git has the other Git—the one you're cloning—list out its branch names.  If that Git is on a Linux system or other system where uppercase and lowercase names are *always* separate, that Git can *always* have two different branch names that differ only in case like this.  Even if that Git is on a system where file names get case-folded, that Git *could* have its branch names stored in places where the case-folding does not happen.

At this point during the `clone` operation, your own Git creates two databases.  These are not very fancy: they are not SQL, for instance.  But they do work as simple key-value stores.

One of these two holds Git *objects*.  The internal names of Git's objects do not cause any problems here so this database always works fine regardless of the underlying file system.

The other database, however, holds branch names, tag names, and other such names.  It stores those as the keys and a Git internal hash ID as the value for each key.  *Initially*, this "database" is a simple plain-text file: you'll find it in `.git/packed-refs`.  Since this is a single file that simply contains lines of text, it can contain two names that differ only in case.  For instance, `.git/packed-refs` could have two lines like this:

```
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88 refs/heads/branch
282ce92448e25cfbf1b399c9d33eb290f2331814 refs/heads/BRANCH
```

(**Note**: it *won't*, because your Git *renames* their branches.  So you'd actually have:

```
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88 refs/remote/origin/branch
282ce92448e25cfbf1b399c9d33eb290f2331814 refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH
```

in here, if this is the result of a fresh clone.  And in fact, this does happen in some cases, and leads to even weirder behaviors, as I'll show below.  But let's just imagine that it did, for a moment.)

This stores two branch names, `branch` and `BRANCH`, and gives them different values.  (The key-value pairs are stored in `.git/packed-refs` as `value key`, for internal reasons, with one key per line.)

But Git doesn't *always* store the name/id key-value pairs in `.git/packed-refs`.

In particular, once a branch name—or any other name—is *updated*, Git stores its value in a stand-alone file.  For the branch named `branch`, this file is `.git/refs/heads/branch`.  Inside this file Git will store the raw hash ID that is the value for that branch name.  Git uses this separate file *because* it does not have a proper database for key-value names.  These files give a way to *simulate* a proper database.

There is one big problem here.  If Git needs to create or update the branch-name `BRANCH`, it will use another, separate and different, file named `.git/refs/heads/BRANCH`.  **This works fine on a typical Linux system** where the file system is happy to store two separate files, one named `branch` and one named `BRANCH`.  **This does not work on a typical Windows or MacOS file system** where the two files are literally the *same* file.  The OS insists on writing any new data to the old file, keeping the name-case from whichever file was created first.

The root of the problem here is Git's attempt to use distinct file names, `.git/refs/heads/branch` and `.git/refs/heads/BRANCH`, when the OS insists that these are the *same* file name.  Git continues to believe that these are two different files, while the OS-and-file-system-combination continues to insist that no, this is *one* file.

#### When you delete the other-case name, Git deletes the (single) file

You now instruct Git to delete one of these two branch names.  It doesn't really matter which one but for concreteness, let's say you tell Git to drop the name `BRANCH`.  Git does this by doing two things:

1. First, it checks whether there's an entry for the name in the `packed-refs` file.  This use a case-respecting comparison, i.e., it doesn't match a `refs/heads/branch` entry, only a `refs/heads/BRANCH` entry.  If an entry like this exists, Git must rewrite or destroy the packed-refs file, as we'll see.
2. Then, having either verified that all is good—that there's no such entry in the packed-refs file, or having rewritten or destroyed it—Git asks the OS to remove `.git/refs/heads/BRANCH`.

If the file that's actually in the OS's file system is named `.git/refs/heads/BRANCH`, the OS removes that file.  If the file that's actually there is named `.git/refs/heads/branch`, the OS removes *that* file instead.  Either way, since the OS literally *cannot* store *both* files, there is now no file at all, of either spelling.

What this means is that since the *line* is not in the packed-refs file and the *file* does not exist, the *branch name itself no longer exists*.  Git's names-to-hash-IDs database no longer has any entry for that branch name, so that branch name no longer exists.

When a branch name doesn't exist, but the `HEAD` file contains that branch name, Git says that you are on a branch that is not yet created.  This state is normal in a new, totally-empty repository.  Since there are no commits, the branch named `master` cannot exist: the name has to hold the hash ID of a valid commit, and there are no commits.  But you're on branch `master` anyway.  So that's normal, if not very common.  (How often are you working with a totally-empty repository?)

You can also enter this state on purpose, using `git checkout --orphan`.  So when Git removes its only copy of some branch name, Git thinks, later, that you must have used `git checkout --orphan` to get into this state.

(Note that deleting a name deletes both the separate file *and* the entry in the packed-refs file, because otherwise the old value comes back.)

#### There's another problem and it actually occurs with remote-tracking names

Note that you cannot be "on" a remote-tracking name:

```
git checkout origin/master
```

puts you in "detached HEAD" mode.  But you *do* have remote-tracking names, and because of what we noted earlier—that they go in `.git/packed-refs`—you can *start out* with remote-tracking names `origin/branch` and `origin/BRANCH` in this file.  So you can have both remote-tracking names.

Your Git gets *updates* from the other Git, though.  These updates might affect one or both of these remote-tracking names.  For instance, suppose their Git's `branch` changes values, and your Git picks up the new value.  Your Git now updates *its* `origin/branch`, and that means that your Git *creates* the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch`.  This file's existence hides, but does not delete, the the old value in the packed-refs file.

If the other Git also updates its `refs/heads/BRANCH`, your Git tries to create a new `.git/refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH` to store the new value.  This, of course, mistakenly overwrites the now-existing `.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch` file, updating the wrong name, and *doesn't* hide the old `BRANCH` value in the packed-refs file.

If the other Git now *deletes* its `refs/heads/BRANCH`, your Git will rewrite your packed-refs file to drop the `refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH` line, and will try to remove `.git/refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH`, which will of course mistakenly remove `.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch`.  The result is that the *old* value of `refs/remotes/origin/branch` becomes the current value of your `origin/branch`.  So it can take one more `git fetch` to correct this state.

When names of both cases exist and identify different commits, and both remote-tracking names are stored in a single file that Git thinks is two separate files, each `git fetch` thinks *one* of the names in your local Git is out of date, and updates it.  This causes the name to alternate, back and forth, between the two values.

All of this behavior is very weird.  It all stems from Git trying to use file names to store branch names *and*, at the same time, insisting that case is significant in branch names.

#### Three possible solutions

Git could fix this in any one of these three ways:

1. Stop using the file system as a cheap form of database.

   If the Git authors put in a real database that does not depend on the OS's "atomic file create" and "atomic rename" operations, the problem would go away.  This is unpalatable because real databases tend to need a lot of code.  Git could use a library such as [Berkeley DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB), perhaps, but even that is a bit complicated.  There are some clear benefits, though.
2. Encode file names.

   Instead of storing `branch` as `.git/refs/heads/branch`, Git could store it as `.git/refs/heads/6272616e6368`, for instance.  The digit-pairs are hexadecimal values representing each character.  Or, store the name `BRANCH` as `.git/refs/heads/_b_r_a_n_c_h` while storing the name `branch` as `.git/refs/heads/branch`.  Encode underscore as double-underscore, so that branch-name `a_12` becomes `.git/refs/heads/a__12`.
3. Give up on case-significance.

   Git could decree that all branch names are always all lower-case, and if you write a branch name as `BRANCH` Git just stores it as `branch` instead.

Method 2 might be the most palatable, but even that is a pretty big shift in operation.  To handle backwards-compatibility it could be enabled only if a `core.refVersion` variable is set to at least 2, and maybe also only if `core.ignoreCase` is set as well.